# Multiple images for Collection

Tags: shopify

By default, you can have only one image for Collection (see screenshot). How do I add 2 images for each collection page? This will be desktop and mobile banner images.

https://www.screencast.com/t/MeznxdQATv

The problem is if I add image field to Collection page schema, the same uploaded image is applied for each Collection page.

Answer (score 0):

You can **upload** an image that you want to show on mobile in **asset** folder. Then you can get collection class name, and can add this code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .collection_element_name {
       background-image: url({{ "your_image.png" | asset_url }});
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Collection Description** and add image directly **using HTML**, so it will be placed on **each collection page separately**